# Filtering and Searching Data with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm, data-structures, salesforce

Where would I start to learn how to filter data like you would see in a product listing page on a shopping site like Nordstrom, Bestbuy, Whirlpool? I want to know how someone would do it with javascript and category and product json data.

https://bestbuyapis.github.io/api-documentation/?shell#categorizations

https://marketplace.intel.com/s/search?search=%7B%22cat%22%3Anull%2C%22q%22%3A%22%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22all%22%7D&language=en_US - This one is kind of confusing to me how they use checkboxes with children. Is this an example of recursion?

Best answer would provide helpful links and an example with explanation. But honestly anything helps!

TIA - just trying to become a better developer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume your JSON represents an array of products, each of which is assigned to zero or more categories, like so:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Apple",
    "category": "fruit",
    "color": "red"
  },
  {
    "name": "Carrot",
    "category": "vegetable",
    "color": "orange"
  },
  {
    "name": "Traffic cone",
    "color": "orange",
  }
]
```

so:

```
const products = JSON.parse(...); // generates an array
```

[Javascript's Array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) are your primary tools, in this case. For example, `Array.filter` can be used to filter by `color`:

```
function filterByColor(color) {
  return products.filter( (product) => {
    return product.color === color;
  });
}
```

If you want to use checkboxes to select more than one color, you could extend it, as follows:

```
function filterByColors(desiredColors) {
  return products.filter( (product) => {
    const { color } = product;
    return desiredColors.includes(color);
  });
}
```

Does this point you in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could fetch and filter the data from the Best Buy API from the front-end (i.e. on a web page).

From the BestBuy API website, here is an example request:
https://api.bestbuy.com/beta/products/openBox(categoryId=abcat0400000)?apiKey=YourAPIKey

And here is the example JSON request:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "customerReviews": {
        "averageScore": "4.7",
        "count": 145
      },
      "descriptions": {
        "short": "Compatible with most Canon DSLR cameras; stepping motor; 52mm filter size; 11.8\" minimum focus distance"
      },
      "images": {
        "standard": "http://img.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/5729/5729048_sc.jpg"
      },
      "links": {
        "product": "https://api.bestbuy.com/v1/products/5729048.json?apiKey=YourAPIKey",
        "web": "http://www.bestbuy.com/site/canon-ef-40mm-f-2-8-stm-standard-lens-black/5729048.p?id=1218688218296&skuId=5729048&cmp=RMX&ky=2l9pmD3wUBb9cc0tkHo49KBFCMPCiIPY4#tab=buyingOptions",
        "addToCart": "https://api.bestbuy.com/click/-/5729048/cart"
      },
      "names": {
        "title": "Canon - EF 40mm f/2.8 STM Standard Lens - Black"
      },
      "offers": [
        {
          "condition": "excellent",
          "prices": {
            "current": 167.99,
            "regular": 199.99
          }
        }
      ],
      "prices": {
        "current": 199.99,
        "regular": 199.99
      },
      "sku": "5729048"
    }
  ]
}
```

Fetch the data, then process the results. You can adjust your filter based on the BestBuy categories and based on what other criteria their API returns (i.e. price, condition, etc.). Below is some sample code that uses the API to get results from the camera category, then only filter out all items above a certain price.

```
//search based on your desired BestBuy category ID - need to look up the IDs from their documentation
//change the searchCategoryID when you want to search for a different category
const getAPIData = (searchCategoryID) =>{
    //used built-in Fetch Web API to perform a get request. Need to get an API Key from Best Buy
    fetch(`https://api.bestbuy.com/beta/products/openBox(categoryId=${searchCategoryID})?apiKey=YourAPIKey`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        //process the data, that is formated like above, with the filter array method
        const dataArr=data.results;
        results.filter(item =>{
            //this is an example where we only keep items less than some target price. You would need to set your filter criteria to what you want 
            //you can only use the data best buy returns in their api
            if(item.prices.current<targetPrice){return true;}
            else{return false;} 
        })
    });
}
```